# How to update a wordpress translation file

Tags: wordpress, localization, po, poedit

I want to localize a wordpress plugin and translate it to Persian with POEDIT.
I created the `fa_IR.po`, `fa_IR.mo` and all the texts loaded but when I write the translation texts and save the file, nothing happens, and it still shows me english texts in front-end.What should I do?!
[image]

Comment: which plugin is it? Does it have any other translations? Have you contacted the author? What folder did you put your translations in? Are any other website components showing translations correctly?

Comment: It's Arena Products Store , I tried editing another plugin's translation file ,but the texts don't change

Comment: If they don't change, maybe your site does not know its supposed to show that language at all? If your site is monolingual, you can change the language in general settings.

Comment: Looking at the comments on that plugin, at http://codecanyon.net/item/arena-products-store-wordpress-plugin/8674943/comments?page=12 , it should be possible to translate, but others have had unsolved ( at least publicly ) issues aswell. If you are still stuck, I recommend posting there and asking the plugin author for further assistance.

Comment: i do that , my wordpress installation is in persian , and all other plugins are in persian but when i change the texts , the texts remain unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly put your fa_IR.mo file in the /wp-content/languages folder?
And did you properly set define( 'WPLANG', 'fa_IR' ); in wp-config.php?

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language

Comment: Defining language in config file is deprecated.